# MemSQL - append query type objects

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, singlestore

MemSQL defines the query type object which can be used inside stored procedures.

You can, for example, do this:
`v_q QUERY(a INT, b INT) = SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b;`

What I'm trying to do is to append different query objects, something like any of the two options below:

Given:

```
q_1 QUERY(a INT, b INT) = SELECT 1, 2;
q_2 QUERY (a INT, b INT) = SELECT 2, 3;
```

First approach:

```
q_3 QUERY(a INT, b INT) = q_2 + q_3;
ECHO q_3;
```

Second approach:

```
ECHO q_2 + UNION SELECT 9, 10;
```

Is there a way to attain this?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of query type variables as representing select statements or views, so your first approach expands out to something like:

```
q_3 QUERY(a INT, b INT) = (SELECT 1, 2) as q_1 + (SELECT 2, 3) as q2;
```

And your second approach expands out to something like:

```
q_3 QUERY(a INT, b INT) = (SELECT 2, 3) as q_2 + UNION SELECT 9, 10;
```

neither of which are valid SQL select statements.

You probably want something like:

```
q_3 QUERY(a INT, b INT, c INT, d INT) = SELECT * FROM q_1 JOIN q_2;
```

which will create a 4 column QUERY type variable with the columns of `q_2` appended to the columns of `q_1`.

Or something like:

```
q_3 QUERY(a INT, b INT) = SELECT* FROM q_1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM q_2;
```

which will create a 2 column QUERY type variable the rows of `q_2` appended to the rows of `q_1`